# Is there a possibility to specify a minimum weight fraction for leaf nodes in XGBoost algorithms?

Tags: python, split, xgboost

I tried to implement a simple XGBoost algorithm and would like to specify a minimum weight fraction of my samples, that should be fulfilled in every leaf node. So far I only found the parameter min_child_weight, which specifies the minimum number of samples in a node. I would like to know if there is a way of how I can incorporate the weight of each sample here, since not each sample has weight=1?

I would be super glad if someone can help here! Thank you :)

Below you can find my code:

```
xg_r = xg.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:squarederror", n_estimators = 10, max_depth = 5, min_child_weight = 500000)
xg_r.fit(X_train, y_train)
xg.plot_tree(xg_r)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example